# Creating Classes with multiple mutable vector attributes in python

Tags: python, numpy

Are the classmethods being used correctly?

I am working on a program to create data input for an 3-D N-body problem. The goal is to create a uniform density sphere with 50000 particles. Each particle class instance must have a mass, position and velocity. The position vector must be in spherical so when the instance of a particle is created it is within a sphere of radius 1. The velocity must be randomized in 3-directions. This will be changed later by adding an orbital velocity. All the data will later be exported into 3 lists masses, position and velocity all in Cartesian coordinates.

I am having trouble creating the particles with such attributes.

The first run of code was:

```
import math
import numpy as np

class Particle:

    def__init__(self,mass,position,velocity):
        self.mass = 1/50000
        self.position = position
        self.velocity=velocity

    def position(self):
        self.position = (self.r, self.theta, self.phi)

    @classmethod
    def set_r(cls, r):
        cls.r = np.rand.uniform(0,1)

    @classmethod
    def set_theta(cls, theta):
        cls.theta = np.rand.uniform(-(math.pi)/2 ,(math.pi)/2)

    @classmethod
    def set_phi(cls, phi):
        cls.phi = np.rand.uniform(0,2*math.pi)  

    def velocity(self):
        self.velocity = (self.Vx, self.Vy, self.Vz)

    @classmethod
    def set_Vx(cls, Vx):
        cls.Vx = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)

    @classmethod
    def set_Vy(cls, Vy):
        cls.Vy = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)

    @classmethod
    def set_Vz(cls, Vz):
        cls.Vz = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)
```

After talking to a friend in the CS department the code was edited to:

```
import math
import numpy as np

class Particle():

    def __init__(self,mass,position,velocity):
        self.mass = 1/50000
        self.position = position[]
        self.velocity = velocity[]


    @classmethod
    def getPosition(cls):
        return [cls.r, cls.theta, cls.phi]

    @classmethod
    def set_r(cls, r):
        cls.position[0] = np.rand.uniform(0,1)

    @classmethod
    def set_theta(cls, theta):
        cls.position[1] = np.rand.uniform(-(math.pi)/2 ,(math.pi)/2)

    @classmethod
    def set_phi(cls, phi):
        cls.position[2] = np.rand.uniform(0,2*math.pi)  

    def getVelocity(cls):
        return [cls.Vx, cls.Vy, cls.Vz]

    @classmethod
    def set_Vx(cls, Vx):
        cls.velocity[0] = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)

    @classmethod
    def set_Vy(cls, Vy):
        cls.velocity[1] = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)

    @classmethod
    def set_Vz(cls, Vz):
        cls.velocity[2] = np.rand.uniform(0,0.001)
```

Do I need to define the parts of the vectors in the **init** and then use a classmethod to create the arrays to be used and changed later?

EDIT 1: The class will be ran trough a for loop to create 50000 particles each with the same mass (normalized to 1/50000), a position vector, and a velocity vector. So exported to a .dat file in a list

Comment: Don't you want to set `mass` to `mass` in your init. also `class` is supposed to be lowercase

Comment: Also how do you intend to use this class?

Comment: The code is to be used in an n-body simulation. Yes the mass should be set to what it is in the init. I assume this needs to be defined outside the class.

Comment: Does the class have a position (that is shared by al instances), or does each instance its own position and velocity?

Comment: Each instance is has it's own position and velocity. The velocity will have to be edited prior to exporting to a .day file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I don't believe you need `classmethod`s here, rather you want to deal with each `Particle` individually. If I'm correct, I believe you're looking for a class that each instance knows it's own `mass`, `position` and `velocity`. I made a class that resembles yours but I used `namedtuples` to represent a `position`, and `velocity`.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple

Position = namedtuple('Position', ('r', 'theta', 'phi'))
Velocity = namedtuple('Velocity', ('Vx', 'Vy', 'Vz'))

class Particle():
    #With 50,000 instances being created, I suggest using __slots__ if possible.
    #This will cut down some on memory consumption.
    __slots__ = ('mass', 'position', 'velocity')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mass = kwargs.get('mass', None)
        self.position = kwargs.get('position', None)
        self.velocity = kwargs.get('velocity', None)

        #Note! This will automatically set random values if any
        #of mass, position, velocity are None when initialized
        #so this may need to be altered if this is undesired
        #this is just a skeleton example and if it works for you it works
        if not any((self.mass, self.position, self.velocity)):
              self.setup_random()

    def setup_random(self):
      self.mass = 1/1500
      self.position = Position(
          r = np.random.uniform(0,1),
          theta = np.random.uniform(-(math.pi)/2 ,(math.pi)/2),
          phi = np.random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
      )
      self.velocity = Velocity(
          Vx = np.random.uniform(0,0.001),
          Vy = np.random.uniform(0,0.001),
          Vz = np.random.uniform(0,0.001)
      )

    def set_r(self, r):
        self.position = self.position.replace(r = r)

    def set_theta(self, theta):
        self.position = self.position.replace(theta = theta)

    def set_phi(self, phi):
        self.position = self.position.replace(phi = phi)  

    def set_Vx(self, Vx):
        self.velocity = self.velocity.replace(Vx = Vx)

    def set_Vy(self, Vy):
        self.velocity = self.velocity.replace(Vy = Vy)

    def set_Vz(self, Vz):
        self.velocity = self.velocity.replace(Vz = Vz)

    def __str__(self):
      return('Mass: {}\nPosition: {}\nVelocity: {}'.format(
          self.mass,
          self.position,
          self.velocity))

    def __repr__(self):
      return('Mass: {}\nPosition: {}\nVelocity: {}'.format(
          self.mass,
          self.position,
          self.velocity))
```

From here you can make as many particles as needed just using `Particle()`

```
p = Particle()
print(p)
```

And this prints:

```
Mass: 0.0006666666666666666
Position: Position(r=0.8122849235862195, theta=-0.060787026289457646, phi=3.415049614503205)
Velocity: Velocity(Vx=0.0006988289817776562, Vy=0.00040214068163074246, Vz=0.0003347218438727625)
```

You can get a value very easily thanks to the `namedtuples` as well:

```
print(p.position.r)
#0.8122849235862195
```

And you can make a particle using pre-defined values like the following:

```
p = Particle(
      mass = 2/5000,
      position = Position(r=1, theta = 2, phi = 3),
      velocity = Velocity(Vx = 4, Vy = 5, Vz = 6))
print(p)
```

Results:

```
Mass: 0.0004
Position: Position(r=1, theta=2, phi=3)
Velocity: Velocity(Vx=4, Vy=5, Vz=6)
```

You will still need the setter methods to set individual values such as `r`, `theta`... as tuples are immutable, **although** you can set a completely new position easily as well Ex:

```
#to set an individual value
p.set_r(1)

#setting a whole new position/velocity
p.position = Position(r = 1, theta = 2, phi = 3)
#or
p.position = Position(r = p.position.r, theta = 2, phi = 3)
#as an example
```

If you want to use a different collection type or anything feel free to do so I just figured `namedtuples` fit well here.

**Edit**

To allow for loading and unloading from a data file; you can make `to_json` and `from_json` methods.

Let's say your data for one Particle looks like:

```
d = {'mass': 0.0006666666666666666,
     'r': 0.8122849235862195,
     'theta': -0.060787026289457646,
     'phi': 3.415049614503205,
     'Vx': 0.0006988289817776562,
     'Vy': 0.00040214068163074246,
     'Vz': 0.0003347218438727625
}
```

Your methods would look like this:

```
def to_json(self):
    json_particle = {'mass': self.mass}
    json_particle.update(dict(self.position._asdict()))
    json_particle.update(dict(self.velocity._asdict()))

    return json_particle

#here we finally use @classmethod
#as we are creating a new instance of the class
@classmethod
def from_json(cls, data):
    pos = Position(r = data['r'], theta = data['theta'], phi = data['phi'])
    vel = Velocity(Vx = data['Vx'], Vy = data['Vy'], Vz = data['Vz'])

    return cls(data['mass'], pos, vel)
```

Comment: Apologies for all the edits, I was trying to make sure I explained enough in detail.

Comment: Haha, we've all been there, I'm here if you have any questions! If this answers your question please don't be afraid to mark it as so I'd really appreciate it :-)

Comment: I think this might answer it. I know that I need to use the values for computation later. So that might take some trivial editing to use an array vs a tuple.

Comment: I made a repl so you can see it in work as well btw, feel free to give it a try: https://repl.it/repls/StormyPleasingAttribute

Comment: So this is going into a Fortran 90 N-body code. The input has to have groups of all the masses, position and velocities. So I am going to have to write a for loop that takes and print them for each instance. For that aim, am I understanding correctly that the to_json and from_json collects the values from the named tuples and puts them into a dictionary? And is the __str__ ; __repr__ responsible for that information being available?

Comment: `str` and `repr` are builtin functions that I am overriding so it prints all pretty essentially. They are not needed but help visualize the data. The `to_json` and `from_json` methods do exactly as you think. They take a dict and make a Particle and the other takes itself and makes a dict in the format I displayed above. I don't have any familiarity with `Fortran 90 N-body code` but if you can send it dict/json data then these methods will come in handy. If you need to send/recieve another datatype then you will need to make a different method for that. Let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: I think I will just need to change the from_json to reflect the grouping I need. The end goal is to group all 50k masses, then positions, then velocities. Rather than print mass, position, and velocities for each.

Comment: I was just making some assumptions so you had at least an example to work with.